# complex scalar extension given complex structure

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Assume $V$ is a real vector space and that $J$ is a complex structure. We define complex scalar multiplication by:

$(a+ib)v=av+bJ(v)$ .  Show that if $v+iw=0$ then $v=0$ or $w=0$.

By definition, $J(v)=iv$. So, $0=v+iw=v+J(w)$. So, $J(w)=-v$. Hence $J^2(w)=J(-v)$. So, $w=J(v)$.

I'm not sure how one can complete this

Comment: I am confused by your question. Say $V$ are the complexes, with the (standard) complex structure. Take $v= -i\in V$, and $w=1\in V$ - counterexample?

Comment: @peterag $V$ is a real vector space

Comment: According to you $w=iv=J(v)$ thus $w$ is zero or $v$ is zero  as w must be real(Note that both must be zero)

Comment: @MathematicallyInterested any complex vector space is also a real vector space, as the reals constitute a subfield of the complex numbers: for instance, if $v_1,\cdots, v_n$ is a basis over $\mathbb C$, then $v_1,\cdots, v_n, iv_1,\cdots, iv_n$ is a basis over $\mathbb R$. On the other hand, a real vector space is ALSO a complex vector space if there is a complex structure on it.

Comment: In particular, $V=\mathbb C$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this claim? It seems that something strange is going on, could just be some notational problem.

Comment: If you want a "reals only" description of peter a g's counter-example: $V = \Bbb R^2$ with $J((x,y)) = (-y,x)$, which you can check is a complex structure. Now consider $v =(0,-1), w = (1,0)$.